# Why is my file getting loaded differently when I add a slash at the end of the file?

Tags: javascript, browser

I have a file which has a path,

> localhost/mj_new/yt/start.php

and it loads this:

[image]

When I add a slash(/) at the end of the file,

> localhost/mj_new/yt/start.php/

it loads the file without external stylesheets and javascripts.

[image]

`start.php` should be considered as a directory in the second case but it isn't and instead something weird is happening.

Comment: If a stylesheet's href is "style.css", the first URL will load `localhost/mj_new/yt/style.css` and the second will load `localhost/mj_new/yt/start.php/style.css`

Comment: Just open your console and you'll understand why (`localhost/mj_new/yt/start.php/style.css` Error 404: file not found)

Answer (score 2):

Because the relative paths are resolved relative to the URL. So given

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css">
```

with your first URL, the path to that is `localhost/mj_new/yt/foo.css`, but with your second URL, it's `localhost/mj_new/yt/start.php/foo.css`.

If you look in your browser's web console, you'll find the paths being used and the 404 errors.

Comment: *(Gah, bad formatting. If you don't see `<link ...>` above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: Yeah, I knew this, I wanted to know why it's being treated as a file if the path is ended with a slash.

Comment: @VermaJr.: So then that has nothing to do with the browser at all. You're asking a question about your web server software's configuration. The whole thing about the CSS and such not getting loaded is also a red herring. If you want to know why you get your page when you request `start.php/`, you should just ask that.

Comment: I got an answer for that in the comment section.